# Region in region verification?

Tags: c++, detection, region

So overall I'm not incredibly familiar with windows programming or programming in general, but I have been fiddling around with trying to create some simple physics using `Create*****Rgn()` and I love that there is a `PtInRgn()` function, but how would I go about testing if a region is inside of another region?

Essentially the effects of a RgnInRgn() function? (**I want to avoid** `RectInRegion()` because even if a region is defined by a rect, i.e. create EllipticRgn() it will detect true for the corners outside the region).

Answer (score 0):

There's an `IntersectRgn` macro in WindowsX.h that calls `CombineRgn`. If there is a way to determine whether a region is empty, this could work.

**Edit:** `CombineRgn`'s return code directly tells you whether the result is empty.

Comment: Hmm, this seems interesting ill have to look into that! Ill respond back after I test it out a bit. (also it just dawned on me that I'm essentially talking about very basic collision detection with regions >.<)

Comment: Windowsx.h seems sort of confusing to me as im not really all that terribly familiar with macros. For now ill try seeing what I can do with POINTs....at least until im a bit more familiar with macros.

Comment: You can just call `CombineRgn` yourself. All `IntersectRgn` does is call `CombineRgn` with the `RGN_AND` value: `CombineRgn(hrgnResult, hrgnA, hrgnB, RGN_AND)`.